# How do I call a SageMaker Endpoint using the AWS CLI (

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to invoke the iris endpointfrom the [SageMaker example notebooks](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/tensorflow_iris_dnn_classifier_using_estimators/tensorflow_iris_dnn_classifier_using_estimators.ipynb) using the aws cli. I've tried using the following command:

```
!aws sagemaker-runtime invoke-endpoint \
--endpoint-name sagemaker-tensorflow-py2-cpu-2018-03-19-21-27-52-956 \
--body "[6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5]" \
--content-type "application/json" \
output.json
```

I get the following response:

```
{
    "InvokedProductionVariant": "AllTraffic", 
    "ContentType": "*/*"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've gotten that response, your request is successful. The output should be in the output file you specified - output.json :)

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, I was running the command for a flask endpoint and wanted to add that when mentioning --body as json I had to add the quotes as:

```
--body "{ \"host\": \"some.example.com\", \"userId\": [ \"some-string\" ] }"
```

I am now looking for a way to specify a json file instead of this body which would be easier for a CI/CD pipeline, per say !